# Adding a text element in between title and blocks container

Tags: javascript, block-editor

Is it possible to add an additional text input before the Blocks editor? I'm trying to update my Subtitle plugin to be Gutenberg compatible, but the subtitle isn't really a "Block" and I think it's more similar to the page title.

Pre-WordPress 5.0, I used the `edit_form_after_title` hook, but in Gutenberg that's irrelevant, so I'm wondering how to inject a new, non-block, element?

Plugin in question: [KIA Subtitle](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kia-subtitle/)

[image: Text input for a Subtitle in the Gutenberg editor. Appears after Title text area and before Blocks container.]

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. You can add it as metabox or use custom template for blocks that will put your custom block as first always.

Comment: building a subtitle block is the way to go

Comment: anything is possible. Possible but not pretty.  If you really want the field right there, you could create a custom field and position it there with JS, then use JS to save the value on blur.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż it currently is a metabox, but it appears at the bottom of the screen which I don't think is good UI for a subtitle.

Comment: @am_ even though a subtitle doesn't really appear just anywhere in the post content?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis That sounds like the answer I usually give to other folks. :) Almost everything IS possible given enough time/resources. :) I'm still very new to Gutenberg, and was hoping there may be some path I don't know about yet.

Comment: We are all new to Gutenberg 

Comment: @RiddleMeThis yeah, but there are things that are possible nice way and things that are nasty hacking - positioning an input with JS is a nasty hacking - tab order will be wrong, RWD won’t work correctly, and so on...

Comment: @helgatheviking I agree that it’s not good UI if it’s somewhere at the bottom. But there is no nice way to put custom inputs after the title. As I mentioned before - “Gutenberg solution” would be to create a custom block, make it appear as first, render as empty and store data in custom field.

Comment: @helgatheviking The subtitle will not appear in the frontend? What is it there for then? Maybe providing a link to your plugin (If in the repository) would help to understand what this is about

Comment: @am_It doesn't appear in the _post content_. No one said anything about it not appearing on the front end.

Comment: Can you maybe replace the title block with a custom one that has two input fields?

Comment: @am_ Link added to the question. But jacob-peatie is correct, it's not in the post content. It's up to the theme developer to add front end display using built-in template tags.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż that does seem like the best option out of not a lot of great options.

Comment: Depressing. Many sites I won't flip to Gutenberg (which I mostly like) due to this.

Answer (score 1):

Initially Gutenberg had plans to implement subheading, See this [ticket](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8234) but later they deprecated it. As of now, there's no hook to do it other than building a custom block. May be in near future you'll find something useful.

I hope this helps